# Error in pandas.to_datetime(String)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create type column using the values from different column like year and month as string fields. And day is a static number, considering first day of month i.e., 1st.

Example:

```
year . month
2015 . 12
2016 . 1
2016 . 2
```

I have tried the following methods to create the Date column but failed

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df['year'],month=df['month'],day=1))

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(str(month)+str(month)+str(1),format=%Y%m%d)

df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x:dt.strptime(str(month)+str(month)+str(1)),format=%Y%m%d)
```

None of the above approaches helped me. Due to cluster requirement using pandas 0.17 version. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First day of each month? Easy.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1))

0   2015-12-01
1   2016-01-01
2   2016-02-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If you run into conversion errors, try adding the `errors='coerce'` argument:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1))
```

The thing to note here is that `pd.to_datetime`, when working with DataFrames, would need at least year, month, and day columns.

Alternatively, pass a single string column to `to_datetime`.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1).astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1))
# pd.to_datetime(df[['col1', 'col2']].assign(day=1).astype(str).agg('-'.join, axis=1))

0   2015-12-01
1   2016-01-01
2   2016-02-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @JackDaniel "The thing to note here is that pd.to_datetime, when working with DataFrames, would need at least year, month, and day columns."

Comment: In your syntax, you haven't mention the year and month column names. How does the function know the year and month values in this case? In my original df, I have different names for year and column.

Comment: @JackDaniel In that case, you must rename them to be "year" and "month" and "day", or else this won't work—try the second option then.

Comment: Any work around without renaming the columns. Renaming the columns does not work in my application as it has lot of further processing.

Comment: @JackDaniel yes, yes, yes, see option 2

Comment: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['shipping_year','shipping_month']].assign(day=1).astype(str).agg('-'.join,axis=1))
  File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2360, in _getattr_
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: @JackDaniel Update your version of pandas, or replace "agg" with "apply".

Comment: ValueError: Unknown string format. The data has unicode issue. Do we have any work around?

Comment: @JackDaniel Add `errors='coerce'` when you call `to_datetime`.

Comment: If I add errors='coerce', all the values are becoming null.

Comment: @JackDaniel Yeah, this is going nowhere. I'm sorry but your data isn't like your example.